# Figure spans two columns, but text going over half the image

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column, journal-publishing, journal

I am using the float package to force an image to right below where the authors section normally is on a journal paper. Using [H] I get the image to show up in the right place, but the text does not properly wrap around the image in the second column. Adding a caption to the image, it seems that LaTeX is not recognizing the figure as spanning two columns since it is forcing the caption to wrap into a single column.

[image: Here is a screenshot of what the attached code produces]

The document style I am using is based on sig-alternate.cls which is a document style for producing two-column camera-ready pages for ACM conferences (a link to this document, image, and my document is below).

Here is the most basic document I could create that reproduces the issue:

---

```
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello World!}

\maketitle

% Figure issue here!
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{DSC_6703d.jpg}
    \caption{This image should span the entire page and the image does, but LaTeX doesn't think it does!}
\end{figure}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non accumsan odio. Aliquam non urna rhoncus nunc viverra tempor. Curabitur gravida volutpat urna in feugiat. Vestibulum aliquet, nunc a adipiscing adipiscing, erat metus semper sapien, ac vestibulum nunc lorem vitae justo. In nec mauris sem. Sed lectus elit, interdum et placerat tincidunt, varius porttitor augue. Sed sit amet enim magna, ut dapibus ipsum. Nunc semper elementum tellus nec consectetur. Duis at odio orci, ut vulputate est.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Mauris sit amet ipsum sed felis mattis tincidunt id et neque. Praesent lorem nunc, ullamcorper eget interdum sit amet, commodo vitae felis. Suspendisse id dolor condimentum libero condimentum dapibus vel non neque. Aenean libero urna, vulputate ac porttitor vitae, mattis convallis metus. Suspendisse enim quam, ultricies eget gravida at, eleifend non libero. Pellentesque a arcu lectus, vitae condimentum leo. In congue cursus diam, vitae sodales mauris viverra quis. Nullam in lectus et justo egestas vestibulum. Ut elementum congue mauris scelerisque condimentum. Sed in ipsum lacus, eget iaculis sem. Nulla semper enim eu nibh ornare ultrices. Curabitur hendrerit euismod massa vitae pulvinar.

Mauris sit amet ipsum sed felis mattis tincidunt id et neque. Praesent lorem nunc, ullamcorper eget interdum sit amet, commodo vitae felis. Suspendisse id dolor condimentum libero condimentum dapibus vel non neque. Aenean libero urna, vulputate ac porttitor vitae, mattis convallis metus. Suspendisse enim quam, ultricies eget gravida at, eleifend non libero. Pellentesque a arcu lectus, vitae condimentum leo. In congue cursus diam, vitae sodales mauris viverra quis. Nullam in lectus et justo egestas vestibulum. Ut elementum congue mauris scelerisque condimentum. Sed in ipsum lacus, eget iaculis sem. Nulla semper enim eu nibh ornare ultrices. Curabitur hendrerit euismod massa vitae pulvinar.

\end{document}
```

---

[image: The image used in the above document]

Also worth noting - if I use figure* instead of figure, when I run QuickBuild in TexMaker or PDFLaTeX, the process hangs indefinitely.

The above document, figure, and document class can be downloaded here: http://cl.ly/0R1K0g3W2v2T

Comment: `fugure` is a single column float so you would need `figure*` however this does not look like it should be a float at all but rather part of `\maketitle` which you could redefine to include the image in its one-column title section before switching to two column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments this should be part of title block, which is already allocating a two-column span. (Use of `[H]` is usually a sign that something isn't right)

[image]

```
\documentclass{document-class}

\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@maketitle{%
\par
\vspace{-5\baselineskip}%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{DSC_6703d.jpg}%
\par
\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hello World!}

\maketitle



\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non accumsan odio. Aliquam non urna rhoncus nunc viverra tempor. Curabitur gravida volutpat urna in feugiat. Vestibulum aliquet, nunc a adipiscing adipiscing, erat metus semper sapien, ac vestibulum nunc lorem vitae justo. In nec mauris sem. Sed lectus elit, interdum et placerat tincidunt, varius porttitor augue. Sed sit amet enim magna, ut dapibus ipsum. Nunc semper elementum tellus nec consectetur. Duis at odio orci, ut vulputate est.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Mauris sit amet ipsum sed felis mattis tincidunt id et neque. Praesent lorem nunc, ullamcorper eget interdum sit amet, commodo vitae felis. Suspendisse id dolor condimentum libero condimentum dapibus vel non neque. Aenean libero urna, vulputate ac porttitor vitae, mattis convallis metus. Suspendisse enim quam, ultricies eget gravida at, eleifend non libero. Pellentesque a arcu lectus, vitae condimentum leo. In congue cursus diam, vitae sodales mauris viverra quis. Nullam in lectus et justo egestas vestibulum. Ut elementum congue mauris scelerisque condimentum. Sed in ipsum lacus, eget iaculis sem. Nulla semper enim eu nibh ornare ultrices. Curabitur hendrerit euismod massa vitae pulvinar.

Mauris sit amet ipsum sed felis mattis tincidunt id et neque. Praesent lorem nunc, ullamcorper eget interdum sit amet, commodo vitae felis. Suspendisse id dolor condimentum libero condimentum dapibus vel non neque. Aenean libero urna, vulputate ac porttitor vitae, mattis convallis metus. Suspendisse enim quam, ultricies eget gravida at, eleifend non libero. Pellentesque a arcu lectus, vitae condimentum leo. In congue cursus diam, vitae sodales mauris viverra quis. Nullam in lectus et justo egestas vestibulum. Ut elementum congue mauris scelerisque condimentum. Sed in ipsum lacus, eget iaculis sem. Nulla semper enim eu nibh ornare ultrices. Curabitur hendrerit euismod massa vitae pulvinar.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick exactly. I stumbled upon a solution in the same vein as the thought behind your implementation by borrowing the teaser macro/command from SIGGRAPH's journal submission template. Many thanks David!